# Update column values in a table from another table's column - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "words" it has a column "score" has all values =0.
and another table "tmp_score" and has a column "sc" has values from 5000 to 1.

I want to update the column "score" in the table "words" to have the values in "tmp_score" column (from 5000 to 1).

I already have 5000 record in the table words.

so i need something like copying these values here.

Comment: How did you say these tables are related, again? Need some column other than just score

Comment: Update table with join and set the other values

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use `join` with `update`.  Assuming the column that matches in the tables is called `word`:

```
update words w join
       tmp_score sc
       on w.word = sc.word
    set w.score = w.sc;
```

Comment: I'd guess that since other table is named `temp_..` it'd have similar columns as original table but OP never mentioned that there is a column `word` in `temp_score` table.